# What's this large filesystem mounted in /media in Ubuntu running in VirtualBox?

Tags: mount, virtualbox

In Virtual Box, when I created it the total size is 300 GB. I have two partitions.
The thing that I don't understand is there is one line shows its size is 840 GB. It is mounted on `/media/sf_Dev`.

[image: 1]

What is that?

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: sda5 2G, sda3 283G, sda1 8G

Comment: Is there an external disk, connected via USB or eSATA? Or is it a partition on the host system's disk? Please edit your original question to show the output of the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f ;  sudo lsblk -m ; sudo parted -ls`

Comment: You can also check the sizes of the partitions in the host system (from the host system). That way you might be able to match a partition to the strange line that you see in the virtual machine. -- Is it a bind mount within the same file system (you have hidden the details)?

Comment: Did you set up shared folder too?

Comment: @George,yes. Also I forgot to mention one point. I resized VirtualBox a couple times but without partitioning it. I just used `gparted` to do it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That large file system belongs to your `host OS` since you set up a shared folder, this is how Virtualbox names its shared folder `sf_<name_of_shared_folder>`. See my image below:

[image]

See my `df -h` run from Virtualbox:

```
george@george-VirtualBox:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M  6.1M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda3        37G  7.9G   27G  23% /
tmpfs           2.0G  216K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       29M  371K   27M   2% /mnt/vfs
/dev/sda1       1.9G  107M  1.6G   7% /boot
/dev/sda4        25G  2.0G   22G   9% /home
leap            909G  691G  219G  76% /media/sf_leap <-- from host OS, that my Hard drive use %
tmpfs           396M   40K  396M   1% /run/user/1000
```

[Except](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto):

> With Linux guests, auto-mounted shared folders are mounted into the /media directory, along with the prefix sf_. For example, the shared folder myfiles would be mounted to /media/sf_myfiles on Linux and /mnt/sf_myfiles on Solaris.